# AS3 to PHP - Getting an "Error #1132: Invalid JSON parse input"

Tags: php, mysql, json, actionscript-3

I am building an AIR app in Flash CS6 using AS3. I need to send the value of the variable `Id` to PHP so that I can choose which data should be shown and also where the data will be displayed.

I have found how to get the data that has been displayed and which are not by entering the `Id` values into an array and take the highest or lowest value.

But the problem is that when I send the data to php I get an error : `SyntaxError: Error #1132: Invalid JSON parse input`

here is my code:

```
var maxId:Number = 0;
var minId:Number = 18;
var phpVars:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
var phpFileReq:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://localhost/social_media_1/timeline.php");
phpFileReq.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
phpFileReq.data = phpVars;
var phpLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
phpLoader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.VARIABLES;
phpVars.maxId = maxId;
phpVars.minId = minId;
phpLoader.load(phpFileReq);

bg2_mc.x = 0;
bg2_mc.y = 305;
addChild(bg2_mc);
timeline_mc.x = 0;
timeline_mc.y = 305;
addChild(timeline_mc);
sampul_mc.x = 0;
sampul_mc.y = 0;
addChild(sampul_mc);
fotoProfil_mc.x = 240;
fotoProfil_mc.y = 85;
addChild(fotoProfil_mc);
navigasi_mc.x = 0;
navigasi_mc.y = 170;
addChild(navigasi_mc);
tempatPost_mc.x = 0;
tempatPost_mc.y = 230;
addChild(tempatPost_mc);
tempatPost_mc.btn.gotoAndStop(2);
tombol1.x = tombol1.width/2;
tombol1.y = tombol1.height/2;
addChild(tombol1);
tombol2.x = tombol2.width/2;
tombol2.y = 100;
addChild(tombol2);

loadTimeline()

function loadTimeline(){
    var phpFileRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://localhost/social_media_1/timeline.php?action=load_timeline");
    var phpLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
    phpLoader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.TEXT;
    phpLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onCompleteLoadTimeline);
    phpLoader.load(phpFileRequest);
}

function onCompleteLoadTimeline(event:Event){
    var result:Object = JSON.parse(event.target.data);

    for (var i:int=0;i<=4;i++){
        tpostArr[i] = new t_post();
        var batas_mc:batas = new batas();

        tpostArr[i].foto.x = 52.50;
        tpostArr[i].foto.y = 52.50;

        tpostArr[i].nama.x = 120;
        tpostArr[i].nama.y = 20;

        tpostArr[i].postingan.x = 120;
        tpostArr[i].postingan.y = 55.15;
        tpostArr[i].postingan.wordWrap = true;
        tpostArr[i].postingan.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.LEFT;

        tpostArr[i].tombol_suka.x = 440;
        tpostArr[i].tombol_suka.y = 73;
        tpostArr[i].nama.text = result[i].timeline_name;
        tpostArr[i].postingan.text = result[i].timeline_post;
        batas_mc.x = 0;
        batas_mc.y = tpostArr[i].postingan.y + tpostArr[i].postingan.height + 20;
        tpostArr[i].addChild(batas_mc);
        idPrint.push(result[i].id);

        timeline_mc.addChild(tpostArr[i]);
        tpostArr[i].y = yPos;
        yPos = tpostArr[i].y+tpostArr[i].height;
        yPos +=5;
        maxId = Math.max.apply(null, idPrint);
        minId = Math.min.apply(null, idPrint);

        var phpVars:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
        var phpFileReq:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://localhost/social_media_1/timeline.php");
        phpFileReq.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
        phpFileReq.data = phpVars;

        phpVars.maxId = maxId;
        phpVars.minId = minId;
    }
}
```

here is my php code:

```
<?php
require_once "connect.php";
$action = isset($_GET['action'])?$_GET['action']:'';
$body_nama = array();
$body_postingan = array();
$total_likers = array();
$id = array();
$minId = URLDecode($_POST['minId']);

switch($action){
case 'posting':
posting();
break;
case 'like':
like();
break;
case 'delet_ini':
deletIni();
break;
case 'load_timeline':
loadTimeline();
break;
case 'load_timeline_baru':
loadTimelineBaru();
break;
}


function loadTimeline(){

global $minId;

$query_offset = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM timeline_posts WHERE id > $minId";
$result_offset = mysql_query($query_offset);
$offset = mysql_result($result_offset,0);

echo $offset;

$jumlah = 10;
$sqldata = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM timeline_posts ORDER BY timeline_posts.id DESC LIMIT $offset,$jumlah");


$rows = array();
while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($sqldata)) {
    $rows[] = $r;
}



echo json_encode($rows);

}

function loadTimelineBaru(){
$maxId = URLDecode($_POST['maxId']);


$query_load = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM timeline_posts WHERE id > '$maxId'";
$result_load = mysql_query($query_load);
$jumlah = mysql_result($result_load,0);
$sqldata = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM timeline_posts ORDER BY timeline_posts.id ASC LIMIT '$jumlah'");

$rows = array();
while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($sqldata)) {
    $rows[] = $r;
}

echo json_encode($rows);
}
?>
```

Comment: Try looking at the request in a tool like Fiddler to see exactly what your PHP code is sending to your swf.  Clearly, the AS3 json parser is reading your PHP code's output as invalid, but we'll need to see the actual json to determine why.

Comment: Okay , but I think the fault lies in the time when sending the value of the variable minId . because I have tried to set a value minId in php and running properly .

Comment: Which line actually triggers the error?

Comment: line 1 until 11 maybe?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will fix your JSON error but I noticed you define the `phpVars` (maxId & minId) **AFTER** you have already sent them using `POST`. Too late to update (eg: `phpVars.maxId = maxId;`) after sending...

Try setting up your code like below & see if it helps...

```
var phpVars:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
phpVars.maxId = maxId;
phpVars.minId = minId;

var phpFileReq:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://localhost/social_media_1/timeline.php");
phpFileReq.data = phpVars; //# assign some data to this request
phpFileReq.method = URLRequestMethod.POST; //# now post (send) the data
```

Comment: The request doesn't get sent to the server until the line saying `phpLoader.load(phpFileReq);` ...